# How is Module.symvers generated?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, embedded

I have an issue trying to build kernel and modules for an embedded system. The resulting Module.symvers has some (a few dozen) entries with invalid (0x00000000) CRC entries.

I'm trying to figure out the process by which Module.symvers is generated so that I can start debugging the problematic entries. However, after looking at the build process for a few hours, I still can't figure out what **generates** Module.symvers.

N.B. - I am looking for the code that actually creates the contents of Module.symvers, not for instructions to "make modules" ;-)

I suspect that the breakage is due to building Linux 3.4.12 with GCC 6.3, but I need to get it working with that config. Disabling modvers is not an option, because I need to load 3rd party binary blob modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of `Module.symvers` has a number of steps. These steps make use of `MODVERDIR` (typically `.tmp_versions` in the build directory) which contains `.mod` files,

After the modules are compiled and corresponding `.o` files are generated, the source is pushed through the C pre-processor with `-D__GENKSYMS__` and the resulting output is piped into `scripts/genksyms`. `genksyms` implements it's own (relatively simple) code parser to generate symbol signatures and their corresponding CRCs. It was the limitations in this parser that prevented `genksyms` from correctly parsing source when using gcc 6.3 on kernel 3.4. (I solved my issue by backporting kernel 4.12 `genksyms`). `genksyms` will produce a `.mod.c` file for each module that contains all the symbol CRCs. This is then compiled to produce `.mod.o` files.

The final step involves parsing all the `*.mod` files in `MODVERDIR`, examining these for all the `.ko` files that make up the modules and passing the corresponding list of `.mod.o` files, together with `vmlinux` to `scripts/modpost`. `scripts/modposts` parses the object files and generates `Module.symvers`.

Answer (score 1):

The file `Module.symvers` is generated by `scripts/modpost`. See the comments at the start of [Makefile.modpost](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/Makefile.modpost), those in the middle of [Makefile.build](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/Makefile.build#L197), and the program itself [modpost.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/mod/modpost.c) which is run with options `-m -i`.

Using `make modules KBUILD_VERBOSE=1` should allow you to see the command being used.